# Customize CrossRider installer

Tags: parameters, customization, browser-extension, crossrider

Let me detail what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have 1 application that (besides the specific app code) also contains a CrossRider extension. Based on the options that the user selects when installing the application, he can enable/disable various features. To do this, my application contains a flag that dictates how it will work (for example if flag = 1 then it will connect to site 1, if flag = 2 then it will connect to site 2 etc.).

I need to be able to pass this flag to my CrossRider extension, but I'm not sure how to do this. In the extension code, I would be using something like this:

```
if (flag == 1)
   InsertFrame(URL_FOR_SITE_1);
if (flag == 2)
   InsertFrame(URL_FOR_SITE_2);
etc.
```

Is there a way to pass this flag to my CrossRider extension? I am hosting the extension on the CrossRider site, but it would not be a problem to host it on a different server if needed.

Thank you,
Mihnea

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it's not possible to pass information directly to the extension, we may have an alternative method of embedding data into our installer's generation mechanism. Please contact our support (support@crossrider.com) and we'd be happy to further discuss your requirements.