# Bundle CrossRider as a single installer

Tags: crossrider

Let me detail what I'm trying to accomplish: I have an application that besides the specific app code and installer, also bundles a CrossRider browser extension. The problem is that my installer generates one entry in *Programs & Features*, while the CrossRider extension generates a different one.

Is there a way to show only my installer in the *Programs & Features*, and hide/have the CrossRider entry to be a part of my main installer?

Thank you,

Mihnea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't an option to hide the Crossrider extension in the Control Panel.
However, if you open a Crossrider support ticket (email support@crossrider.com) the person who deals with such matters (who is away this week) will be happy to discuss any options we can consider implementing to assist you.

Comment: Thank you @Shlomo, I will send a support ticket for this. If you have the time, maybe you can also assist me with another question on CrossRider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882802/customize-crossrider-installer - thank you again.

Comment: Regarding the other question, I answered there in a similar manner :-)